# Add Qt to an existing Visual Studio 2013 C++ project

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013

I have an existing `C++` project in `Visual Studio 2013`. I need to add a `Qt` form to it. Is there an automated/simple way to do it? Otherwise, which steps do I have to follow?

Comment: Install the Qt Addin For Visual Studio and Qt for VS2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 2013, i'd suggest you to use the Qt VsAddin. It will automatically configure your project for Qt and contains wizard from specific Qt classes creations.